# Data append to list using XLRD

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlrd

I am able to import data of rows in a particular column of certain sheet name in to a python list. But, the list is looking like `Key:Value` formatted list (not the one I need).

Here is my code:

```
import xlrd

excelList = []

def xcel(path):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    impacted_files = book.sheet_by_index(2)
    for row_index in range(2, impacted_files.nrows):
        #if impacted_files.row_values(row_index) == 'LCR':
        excelList.append(impacted_files.cell(row_index, 1))
    print(excelList)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xcel(path)
```

The output is like below:

```
[text:'LCR_ContractualOutflowsMaster.aspx', text:'LCR_CountryMaster.aspx', text:'LCR_CountryMasterChecker.aspx', text:'LCR_EntityMaster.aspx', text:'LCR_EntityMasterChecker.aspx', text:'LCR_EscalationMatrixMaster.aspx',....]
```

I want the list to have just values. Like this...

```
['LCR_ContractualOutflowsMaster.aspx', 'LCR_CountryMaster.aspx', 'LCR_CountryMasterChecker.aspx', 'LCR_EntityMaster.aspx', 'LCR_EntityMasterChecker.aspx', 'LCR_EscalationMatrixMaster.aspx',...]
```

I've tried pandas too (`df.value.tolist()` method). Yet the output is not what I visualize.

Please suggest a way.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accumulating a list of cells, and what you are seeing is the `repr` of each cell in your list. Cell objects have three attributes: `ctype` is an int that identifies the type of the cell's value, `value` (which which is a Python rtype holding the cell's value) and xf_index. If you want only the values then try

```
excelList.append(impacted_files.cell(row_index, 1).value)
```

You can read more about cells in the [documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Cell).

Comment: Is it possible to include a condition where if a cell value starts with certain string, then only append to a list? I tried with startswith method (if impacted_files.startswith(‘LCR’)) and found it isn’t a valid attribute.

Comment: Again it's a question of knowing what type of object you are dealing with. `startswith` is a string method, and so can only be used with strings. For a string-valued cell you could use something like `if impacted_files.cell(row_index, 1).value.startswith('LCR'):`. If you are doing lots of processing on a single cell, assign it (or its `value`) to a variable and use that instead.

Comment: Thank you very very much @holdenweb. I learnt something new yet very important to my work.

Comment: I have sympathy with anyone who has to learn to program to get results they need, so I try to help. To expand your knowledge, see what happens if you put a numeric value in one of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try one more library, `openpyxl` this is how it can be done.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook(path)
sh = book.worksheets[0]
print([cell.value for cell in row for row in sheet.iter_rows()] )
```

Comment: It works pretty much the same way in `xlrd` - it's the pythonic thing to do!